# When i try to access my site's rss feed, It automatically downloads the XML file instead of displaying it on browser

Tags: php, wordpress

please help me finding out why this is happening. I use Wordpress for building my site.

Comment: Can you give us any link? What browser do you use? Do you use any plugins? You need to give us more information before we can help you.

Comment: In firefox, it prompts for download. In Chrome It displays in XML format instead of proper format

Comment: Read this: [Firefox tries to download my RSS feed](http://textpattern.com/faq/181/firefox-tries-to-download-my-rss-feed)

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful.

Comment: @EliasNicolas - broken link